# Mac Numbers Using One Table To Edit Another

Tags: javascript, macos, applescript, spreadsheet

It seems like something that should be simple, and it probably is but my mind is being dense and not helping me. I have two Tables in a sheet on Numbers. The first acts as a master list of titles, and the second acts as a list of titles used. I simply want a way to remove everything that has been used from the master list so that the first table no longer contains them. Can someone help me with a script or simple way to do this?

Have tried scripts when I had this both on one table:

```
tell application "Numbers"
    activate
    tell front document
        tell sheet 1
            set masterList to value of cells of column "B"
            set usedList to value of cells of column "C"
            
            repeat with i from (count of masterList) to 1 by -1
                set masterItem to item i of masterList
                if masterItem is in usedList then
                    delete cell i of column "B"
                end if
            end repeat
            
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: Please show what you tried. We'll help you fix it, we won't write it for you.

Comment: You probably don't need to use AppleScript for this, it seems like there should be built-in operations for it. But I don't know spreadsheets well enough to suggest what it would be. [apple.se] might be a better place to ask about using Numbers.

Comment: @user717452 You should delete this question on this site. Cross-posting is generally discouraged.